# Два компа с одинаковыми MAC адресами в одной сети

Tags: ip, mac, switch, router, ethernet

Всем привет, возник вопрос, как подключить два (а то и несколько) ПК в одну сеть с разными IP, но одинаковыми MAC адресами сетевых плат, и чтобы все работало?

Comment: Что вам мешает просто сделать MAC разными?

Comment: Если коротко, то никак. Почитайте зачем нужен MAC и как работает Ethernet (хотябы в плане маршрутизации пакетов)

Comment: Нужен хаб (не свитч!) - к нему подключаете все свои платы. Снаружи будет смотреться как один мультихом. Будет глючить, если эти ИП будут обслуживать стандартные сервисы имён, вплоть до укладывания всей сети. Альтернатива - отдельный маршрутизатор перед каждым компом, и без клонирования МАС.

Comment: @andreymal - наверное автор хочет подключить к домашней сети 2 компа, но провайдер требует привязки каждой квартиры к одному мак-адресу (в провинции везде такая хрень).  хочешь подключить 2 компа - покупай роутер, а обычный 5-портовый свитч тебе не поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Формальный ответ, без учёта фактических условий (отсутствуют в вопросе): Задайте им всем MAC = FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF - так будет работать :)

Но так делать не стоит, т.к. это создаст ненужную нагрузку на сеть, и так как пакеты к таким оплучателям будут получать все, то и с безопасностью тоже будет непорядок.

Comment: это такая шутка?

Comment: Это решение для нестандартного случая, описанного автором.